# https over http proxy socket connection in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, http-proxy

I'm trying to write a simple 'https over http tunnel' server in python.
Every other thing works out fine except the connection between the client and the server persist and ends up blocking( forever ).
I'm pretty sure they carry out the SLL handshake because they both send and receive a couple of times before it hangs.

here's the server code:

```
import socket
import threading

class SocketWrapper:
    def __init__(self,sock = None):
        if sock is None:
            self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        else:
            self.socket = sock


    def connect(self,host,port):
        try:
            self.socket.connect((host,int(port)))
            return True
        except socket.error:
            return False

    def close(self):
        # close the socket connection
        self.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        self.socket.close()

    def send(self,data):
        bytes_sent = 0
        msg_len = len(data)
        while bytes_sent < msg_len:
            sent = self.socket.send(data[bytes_sent:])
            bytes_sent += sent

    def receive(self):
        chunks = []
        while True:
            try:
                self.socket.settimeout(0.5)
                chunk = self.socket.recv(4096)
                chunks.append(chunk)
            except socket.error:
                self.socket.settimeout(0)
                break;


        return b''.join(chunks)

class HttpTunnel:

    def __init__(self,host='localhost',port=3000):
        # create the server socket,bind and listen
        self.host,self.port = host,port
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        self.socket.bind((self.host,self.port))
        self.socket.listen(3)
        print("listening on port",self.port)
        self.running = True


    def handleClientRequest(self,connection,address):
        print("Connected to",address)
        clientSocket = SocketWrapper(connection)
        
        meta = clientSocket.receive().decode().split('\r\n')[0]
        # getting method,uri,version from 'CONNECT host:port HTTP/1.1'
        method,uri,version = meta.split(' ')
        host,port = uri.split(':')

        serverSocket = SocketWrapper()
        # if connection to the remote server is created successfuly
        if(serverSocket.connect(host,port)):
            print("Connected to remote server")
            # send connection success message to the client
            clientSocket.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n');
            
            while True:
                try:
                    clientResponse = clientSocket.receive()
                    serverSocket.send(clientResponse)
                    print("Sent client - server")
                    serverResponse = serverSocket.receive()
                    clientSocket.send(serverResponse)
                    print("Sent server - client")
                except socket.error:
                    break;
        else:
            # send someking of error. In this case 404
            serverSocket.send(b'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n')
        # close the connection
        clientSocket.close()
        serverSocket.close()


    def mainloop(self):
        while self.running:
            # accept client connection
            connection,address = self.socket.accept()
            self.handleClientRequest(connection,address)

proxy = HttpTunnel()
proxy.mainloop()
```

the client code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request as request
proxy = request.ProxyHandler({
    'https':'https://127.0.0.1:3000'
    })
opener = request.build_opener(proxy)

 
request.install_opener(opener)
try:
    resp = request.urlopen('https://google.com')
    print(resp.read())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

the client did not get the response from the server and therefore prints nothing.

here's the server output:

```
listening on port 3000
Connected to ('127.0.0.1', 54888)
Connected to remote server
Sent client - server
Sent server - client
Sent client - server
Sent server - client
Sent client - server
```

Comment: This proxy setting does not specify HTTPS over HTTP but HTTPS over HTTPS, i.e. use `http://..` in the proxy URL not `https://...`. Apart from that your code has some debug output but you don't add any output in your question - which makes understanding your problem unnecessary hard.

Comment: how can I do that? Previously I included a 'http': 'address' setting for the proxy handler but it sends a http request(unencrypted) for any url that uses http. I got the http-tunnel specification from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel)

Comment: *" but it sends a http request(unencrypted) for any url that uses http."* - yes, this is how HTTP proxies behave. Plain HTTP will stay plain HTTP and HTTPS will be passed through a tunnel created with the CONNECT request.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here:

- The main problem is that you don't handle the case when `recv` returns 0 since the socket gets closed. Instead you run into an endless loop where no data get read and no data get send. Some simple print statements which actually show how much data are read would have helped to track this problem down.
- Apart from that the idea of polling each file handle after each other using settimeout is a bad approach. Instead check the file handles in parallel and then read from the one which has data - see [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html).
- And finally you are assuming that [socket.send](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) will send all data given. This is not the case, it might send less. Check the return code or just use [socket.sendall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It turns out the problem was with the receive method in the SocketWrapper class, I also noticed it was taking up lots of memory( appending b'' to the chunks buffer)  after it ran for a while.